# Microphone question in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, audio-recording

I am trying to do an app, to where when it launches, it will detect audio, and then play it back automatically. NO BUTTONS, nothing to press. Just a picture of something then, it listens for audio, then plays it back. Similar to the Talking Carl app in the App Store. Any ideas/help? Would appreciate it, if i could use the code with IB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has released a document named [Audio & Video Coding How-To's](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/). I’d suggest you start with “[How do I record audio from the built-in microphone?](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/#AUDIO_RECORDING-RECORD_AUDIO_FROM_THE_BUILT_IN_MICROPHONE)”, read “[How do I record and play back audio at the same time?](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/#PLAYBACK-RECORD_AND_PLAY_BACK_AUDIO_AT_THE_SAME_TIME)”, and, finally, check out the [aurioTouch project](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007770). Good luck!